# DIV width adjustment

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have two `<div>`-s in a page arranged side by side with width defined in percentage say `75%` and `25%`. Everything goes well in 100% browser zoom , but as soon as I zoom in one `<div>` falls down. How to prevent this?

If it can't be prevented for ALL zoom sizes then can I detect that my `<div>` has fallen and give the user an alert possibly to zoom out?

Answer (score 1):

You could set a `min-width` for your `body` which would make the page scroll instead of resizing.

Comment: do I have to set it in pixels?

Comment: You can also use `em`s or percentages. Are these divs inside another element, or within the body itself? If they're within another element, you could also try `overflow-x: scroll`

Comment: I tried both the things.. somehow NOT working.. the right <div> always falls down, actually it has some images.. when the images are zoomed in, in just doesn't adjust automatically.. A scroll would be perfect

Comment: actually the element from the side <div> also creep into its space

Comment: Try adding `overflow:scroll` to the `<div>`s themselves, the problem may be that the images are zooming and causing the div to become too large.

Comment: see what exactly happens @ www.law-firm-india.com

Answer (score 0):

It should zoom just fine. Put a "float:left" on your 75%/left DIV and a "float:right" on your 25%/right DIV...or vice versa. Example:

```
<div style="width:75%; height:200px; background:#333; float:left; position:relative;"></div>
<div style="width:25%; height:200px; background: #999; position:relative; float:right;"></div>
```

Comment: IT doesn't :(, These are my styles

Comment: #templatemo_wrapper {
 width: 76%;
 padding: 0 10px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: url(images/templatemo_body_2.jpg) top center no-repeat;
 display:inline-block; 
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 border-width:1px; 
 border-style:solid; 
 border-color:black;
 border-bottom-style:hidden;
}

#templatemo_wrapper_right {
 width: 24%;
 padding: 0 10px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display:inline-block; 
 float:right;
 position:relative;
}